# 404 Not Found nginx/1.12.2 - in foreach with File_get_contents

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I've tried in several ways and still can not solve. I have an array with many urls, I use foreach to access the site and extract data with `file_get_contents()`

But `404 Not Found nginx/1.12.2` is the error that appears after approximately 2 minutes and registering approximately 280 records.

In addition to trying to execute `max_execution_time` and `mysql.connect_timeout` by inserting in the code also changing in the `ini.php` the value of `0` or `1200`, the result is always the same, after 2 minutes it displays the error `404 Not Found nginx / 1.12.2`

in the code I tried to use `set_time_limit (0);` and `sleep (1)` but it is not solving the problem either

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout','0');   
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');   

function create_wordpress_post_with_code() {

    if( isset( $_POST['mysubmitbtn'] ) ) {
        set_time_limit(0);

        $myGetCsv = function ($str) {
            return str_getcsv($str, ';');
        };

        $lines = array_map($myGetCsv, file(''.get_template_directory_uri() . '/list.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));    

        foreach($lines as list($var1, $var2)){

            set_time_limit(0);  

        $html = file_get_contents( 'https://example.com/'.$var1.'/'.$var2' ); 
        $document = new DOMDocument();              
        @$document->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $domxpath = new DOMXPath($document);

         // more code here

                $post_id = wp_insert_post(
                            array(
                                'comment_status'    =>   'open',
                                'ping_status'       =>   'closed',
                                'post_author'       =>   $author_id,
                                'post_name'         =>   $slug,
                                'post_title'        =>   $title,
                                'post_content'      =>   $content,
                                'post_status'       =>   'publish',
                                'post_type'         =>   'post'
                            )
                        );
         sleep(1);

        }

    }


} 
add_action( 'init', 'create_wordpress_post_with_code' );
```

What can I do to resolve this error? Or what are the probable reasons that this error is happening besides possibly because of the execution time?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `"` in string whenever you have to use variables. Other wise its value will not be interpreted.
 Change

```
$html = file_get_contents( 'https://example.com/$var1/$var2' );
```

to

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://example.com/$var1/$var2");
```

Or concatenate string with `.`

```
$html = file_get_contents( 'https://example.com/'.$var1.'/'.$var2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was just a typo in my question, the code is working normally, the only problem is that upon arriving 2 minutes does not continue to register the list and the error is displayed