# Delete csv lines in foreach

Tags: php, csv, foreach, fopen

I have a large list, how do I for every loop in the foreach be excluded from the file 'list.csv' the line that passed through the foreach?

```
$myGetCsv = function ($str) {
    return str_getcsv($str, ';');
};    

$lines = array_map($myGetCsv, file(''.get_template_directory_uri() . '/list.csv'));     

foreach($lines as list($var1, $var2)) {
    //CODE
}
```

example:

original file:

```
test1, subtest1;  // test1 is $var1 and subtest1 is $var2
test2, subtest2;
test3, subtest3;
```

list.csv after the first foreach

```
test2, subtest2;
test3, subtest3;
```

list.csv after the second foreach

```
test3, subtest3;
```

list.csv after the third foreach

```
empty
```

Comment: That is, always delete the first line of file?

Comment: @felipsmartins yes, always the first

Comment: @felipsmartins Thinking fine, it has to match the line just passed in the foreach, the line can never pass again in the foreach

Comment: how large is the list? Depending on size, just invoke `file()` function and then `array_shift()` and then `file_put_contents(join("\n", $lines))` or something like this...

Comment: around 5 thousand lines

Comment: @felipsmartins I think I understood what you suggested, but I still did not understand how I would identify the line that will be excluded

Comment: well... just add an... if statement before `unset($lines[$key])`? - hm... se a linha a ser deletada está sob uma condição, apenas delete o elemento do array retornado por `files()` acessando-o pela chave da iteração atual no foreach.

Comment: Do you really want to remove the line from the CSV file? Or you want to process one line at a time?

Comment: @Pablo I can already access one line at a time, but I happen to have tried in several ways to correct the error [404 Not Found nginx/1.12.2 - in foreach with File_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144031/404-not-found-nginx-1-12-2-in-foreach-with-file-get-contents) This error only allows to register approximately 300 lines and then I have to run the script again. But to ensure and avoid duplicate records I want to simply delete each row in the foreach and then click on re-run the code

Answer (score 1):

Base on your clarifications in the comments it looks like the only reason why you are trying to delete the lines from the file is because you can't load the entire file in memory and want to parse the large file in multiple execution of the script.

If the above statement is accurate the short answer is that you do not have to load the entire file in memory.

You can use the class [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) to iterate through the whole file one by one. Just make sure that within the loop you are NOT caching the rows in memory and are saving it to the new destination like a database.

Example:

```
$file = new SplFileObject('/path/to/file/list.csv');
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$file->setCsvControl(';');

// Iterate through the whole file reading on line at a time
foreach ($file as $row) {
    list($var1, $var2) = $row;

    // Do what you want her but do not keep row info in memory
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Please, when I call the function how do I not to keep the row in memory when calling the function again?

Comment: Do not save the data from `$row` into another variable. Ex: `$lines[] = $row`.

Comment: this error is appearing `SplFileObject::rewind(): stream does not support seeking`

Comment: I tried to guide you in the right direction with the original issue you were having but i am afraid I won't be able to help troubleshoot the rest of your script. Refer to the php doc or google further errors that come up. Good luck!